# How to create a commit status in GitHub?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

I want to set a commit status in my personal repo. I'm following the directives in this url https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/statuses When I hit the GitHub REST API with the following request, I get the response below:

```
 curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" -H "Authorization: token <TOKEN>" https://api.github.com/repos/andresdiegolanda/hello-world/commits/7f7e31e1956bb76e29fb94d1345954d5cb407c96
```

[image]

As you can see, there are no status in this commit. Then, I try to set a status in the commit with the following request, and I get the response below.

```
  curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" -H "Authorization: token <TOKEN>" https://api.github.com/repos/andresdiegolanda/hello-world/578138334ad1f8dc874886ed2afb99e3265565be -d '{"state":"success","target_url":"https://example.com/build/status","description":"The build succeeded!","context":"continuous-integration/jenkins"}'
```

[image]

My question is: What am I doing wrong, that doesn't allow me to set the status in the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The the [Create commit status API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/statuses#create-a-commit-status)

```bash
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \ 
  -H "Authorization: token <TOKEN>" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/statuses/SHA \
  -d '{"state":"success","target_url":"https://example.com/build/status","description":"The build succeeded!","context":"continuous-integration/jenkins"}'
```

In your example:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/andresdiegolanda/hello-world/578138334ad1f8dc874886ed2afb99e3265565be
```

I did not see the `/statuses/` part.

The other option is to use the [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/):

```bash
# GitHub CLI api
# https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api

gh api \
  --method POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  /repos/OWNER/REPO/statuses/SHA \
  -f state='success'
 -f target_url='https://example.com/build/status'
 -f description='The build succeeded!'
 -f context='continuous-integration/jenkins'
```

Comment: Brilliant. That worked. I was missing the "statuses"